# Are axioms in mathematics comparable to hypotheses in experimental sciences?

Tags: logic, axioms

Remark: my question deals more particularly with the axioms of set theory, arithmetic, probability theory, etc. I think the status of the axioms in geometry is clearer.

The French fictitious mathematician  Bourbaki writes somewhere ( " The Architecture of Mathematics " in Jean-François Le Lionnais, Great Currents Of Mathemaatical Thought ) that the approach of the mathematician is comparable to the way experimental science proceeds.

The physicist makes observations and looks for the best explanation: he adopts as his theory the hypothesis ( or set of hypotheses) from which these observations can be deduced at minimuml cost.

If the comparison holds, the " observations" would, in mathematics, be some pieces of mathematical knowledge the mathematician wants to " secure" or justify , and the axioms would be the best available explanation. For example, the mathematician first wants addition to be commutative, multiplication to distribute over addition, etc.,  and after that, he seeks  hypothesis or axiom(s) from which this desired results could follow.

My question is : is this view of axiomatizing in mathematics correct? and could  this conception of axiomatizing be helpfull to correct the feeling  of gratuitousness or arbitrariness of axioms?

Comment: why is this tagged as algebra-precalculus or graphing-functions?

Comment: my mistake, i'll correct this

Comment: In science, hypotheses can be disproved by experiment; in math, axioms are assumed to be true without proof.  Perhaps mathematicians could make observations and come up with a theory to be tested, but *axioms* are assumed, not tested

Comment: They are very different: hypotheses are ideas to be tested to see whether they can be shown to be wrong empirically, while axioms are assumed to be true and the logical consequences explored (any test would be about logical inconsistency with or independence of other axioms)

Comment: The method of testing is very different, that's true. Under this aspect, the comparison does not hold. Can one say however that the reason we have to adopt this axiom rather that this other one is his "explanatory power" ( as it is the case, I think, in natural sciences)?

Comment: But there was a long search for the appropriate axioms for probability theory, for example.

Comment: @ saulspatz  - Any reference on this topic? I'd like to know what was going wrong with the first axioms probability theorists were working with.

Comment: I think this is going to lead to a quagmire of opinion-based comments. Here are two facts: Bourbaki wasn't a mathematician and you haven't given adequate references for any of the statements you make about Bourbaki, Dieudonne, Russell or "the natural scientist". Until you provide the references, your question is a waste of time on MSE.

Comment: OK. I'll edit my post as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are some similarities and some differences.

Marcus du Sautoy once attempted in a documentary to distinguish mathematics from empirical sciences by arguing that, whereas Einstein refuted Newtonian mechanics, the truths of Euclidean geometry stand forever. My issue with him saying this is that both theories have the following similarities, which through sleight of hand he tries to pretend is a difference: the fact that their axioms imply specific theorems cannot be overturned, and their theorems have been empirically shown to fail as descriptions of our world. (The universe's geometry appears to be Riemannian, not Euclidean.)

But what do mathematicians and scientists do when such empirical failures occur? Scientists look for new theories that don't have the same flaws, while retaining old ones in their domains of applicability and for teaching purposes. Mathematicians keep using old theories with the same aplomb as before. They don't need their theories to describe specific things in Nature, because such descriptions are appended to "look at this maths for its own sake", which is all that maths requires. That Euclidean geometry can't serve astronomers well any more doesn't detract from its "default" status in ordinary mathematics. (If you post a problem about a triangle on here, without saying the geometry is non-Euclidean, no-one will even mention the unspoken assumption that the geometry *is* Euclidean.)

Where mathematicians *do* reject a system of axioms is when they lead to logical contradictions. That's why set theorists go nowhere near unrestricted comprehension. The response to Russell's paradox seems straightforward *now*, but a lot of systems of axioms got debated in its immediate aftermath. If we ever find a contradiction in ZFC, we'll have to start over again.

Comment: I agree with Sautoy's remarks: In mathematics, Riemannian geometry builds on but also depends on Euclidean geometry, while in physics relativity replaces Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @RobArthan No, new physics still builds on the old.